# Согласование с числительными

Tags: согласование

Как правильно согласовать словосочетание "конечных потребителей" с числительным?

Варианты:

1. Так, за предыдущий год нами была поставлена продукция более 100 конечным потребителям и на сегодняшний момент от большинства получены положительные отзывы.
2. Так, за предыдущий год нами была поставлена продукция более чем сотне конечных потребителей и на сегодняшний момент от большинства получены положительные отзывы.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант точно не годится из-за отсутствия слова ***чем***. А также ***сто*** лучше писать словом. Второй, на мой взгляд, нормальный. Можно заменить и на *"более чем ста конечным потребителям".* Но ваш вариант *(более чем сотне)* звучит, по-моему, изящнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

ОТВЕТ ИЗМЕНЕН

Обе формы употребляются, но правильно: **более чем ста** конечным потребителям, **более чем сотне** конечных потребителей.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) **Более чем** - наречное выражение, которое не влияет на падеж количественного сочетания.

2) Ста конечным потребителям: согласование в Д.п. для числительного.

3) Сотне конечных потребителей: сущ. "сотня" задает Р.п. зависимому слову.

4) Слово **"более"** также задает Р.п. зависимому слову: более ста,  более сотни, поэтому **используется только в И.- В. падежах**. **В других падежах следует использовать выражение "более чем".**

Нельзя сказать "более 100 конечным потребителям", правильно: более 100 конечных потребителей (И.п.), более чем ста конечным потребителям  (Д.п.)

Запятая в сложном предложении, скорее, ставится, так как используются разные обстоятельства времени.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Скажите, Вера, а ***чем*** действительно можно "выбросить"? Вы уверены? Неужели можно сказать "поставлена более сотн**е** конечных потребителей"?

Comment: Тут, видимо, имеется в виду: более ста конечным потребителям. А по поводу запятой - это потому что можно сказать _"за предыдущий год нами была поставлена продукция... и поэтому"_? Или то, что _"была поставлена"_ и _"на сегодняшний момент получены"_?

Comment: Артем, Вы правы по поводу "более сотне конечных потребителей", ответ изменен.